# Is there a way to rollup a field from child to grandparent?

Tags: roll-up-summary

i've a custom object Score has to be rollup to grand parent Account. Score-project-account is the lookup currently. How to get count of a field of score onto account?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options,

**1. Flow**

- Create a flow which runs when Score object Record Created
- Get Parent Project Record Id - Store it in a variable
- use `get Records` to get all child records (Score object) of Project
- Loop through all Child records and use a variable in the Loop to keep track of Count of records
- Update count on Parent Project record in a custom field (ex. `Score Count`)
- Create a Roll up summary on Account which rolls up the New `Score Count` field.

**2. Workflow/Process Builder**

- Every time Score record is Created or Project record is updated
- Update Account field on SCORE object (a lookup field)
- Add a roll up summary field on Account to roll up All Score object records.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationships are all lookups which don't support rollup summaries you could use this package https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries

Create a DLRS from the child to parent, and again from the parent to the grandparent.